# Subset Field and Irrdeduciblity

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose $F \subset K$ are both fields. Let $f \in F[x]$. Suppose $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$. Prove $f$ is also irreducible in $F[x]$.

---

Want to prove by contradiction.

$f$ is reducible in $F[x]$. So $f\in F[x]\subset K[x]$ so the same operations apply in $K[x]$ making $f$ reducible in $K[x]$. But $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$.

It cannot be that easy? Missing something?

Comment: It's too complicated. Prove the contrapositive.

Comment: Since $F\subseteq K$, any equation of the form $f=gh$ in $F[X]$ is valid in $K[X]$, and hence the result. This is your argument, and it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments

***Proof***:(By contradiction)

f is reducible in $F[x]$. 
$$ \exists \text{ non unit, non associate } g(x),q(x) \in F[x]:f(x)=g(x)q(x)$$

Since $f\in F[x] \subset K[x]$ so $f(x),g(x),q(x)\in K[x]$
same operation operate in $K[x]$. Making $f$ reducible in $K[x]$. Contradiction $f$ is irreducible in $K[x]$